# Cocos2D Library Leak?

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, memory-leaks, analyzer

My Xcode analyze tool is showing a leak coming from the Cocos2D library (CCAtlasNode.m).
Anyway how would I fix this leak?

```
self.textureAtlas = [[CCTextureAtlas alloc] initWithFile:tile capacity:c];
[textureAtlas_ release];
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Make sure the same leak happens in a freshly created project, to avoid side effects like this one: [How to determine where this memory leak is coming from?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1270284/how-to-determine-where-this-memory-leak-is-coming-from)
2. Once you're 100% sure the leak is coming from cocos2d-iphone, [report it to the developers](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/forum/13) with all the information you have.

Comment: Is there any way to just make the compiler forget this leak? It doesn't seem like it is a real like but just a compiler bug. What would fix it?